# Get svn log from repository, not working copy

Tags: linux, svn

I want to get the log's from a svn repository. Now, I'm capable of doing this in two ways, make a local repository and get the svn logs from there. Or, number 2, get it from the DAV/HTTP served svn repository.

Is there a way to get the svn logs directly from the repository folder? (The one with conf,db,gooks,etc in it?). If I do

```
svn log <repodir>
```

I get the error 'svn: '/var/repositories/test' is not a working copy'. With

```
svnlook log
```

I get just a empty line as a return.

Thanks.

Comment: Try using `svn log file:///path/to/your/repo`

Comment: Yes, that was indeed the solution. If you give it as an answer, I'll accept it :)

Comment: it's better to call `svn log` on a copy, i.e. a checked out version of the repository, than the repository itself.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to use the `file://` protocol, so the parameter gets parsed as URL (repositories can only talked to with an URL):

```
svn log file:///path/to/your/repo
```

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to get the svn logs directly from the repository folder?

Use file:/// protocol

`svn log file:///D:/Repositories/Hello` there D:/Repositories/Hello is full path to repo with slashes in path instead Win-backslashes